# Is Sharepoint 2007 incompatible with Office 2013?

Tags: 2007

We have upgraded to Office 2013 and now when I try to Check Out an Excel Spreadsheet housed in Sharepoint 2007 there is no file downloaded to my Local Sharepoint Drafts folder.

After doing a Check out I searched all local and network drives but it is not found anywhere.

Can anyone tel me what is happening and if there is a solution to this problem

Updating to Sharepoint 2013m is not an option right now.

TGG

Comment: Which is your browser version?

Comment: also what version of office did you have and the one running now is it in 64 or 32? is the browser running in 32bit?

Comment: We are using IE8  and Have been on Windows 7 64 bit all through the process.  The only thing that has changed was the upgrade to Office 2013

Comment: We were previously running Office 2010

Answer (score 1):

If I use the same account in SharePoint 2007 (SP2) web application as in excel, I have no trouble to check out, edit, check in and publish Excel 2013 spreadsheets. I can use the dropdown of the spreadsheet in SharePoint, or use Excel 2013 directly in my recent spreadsheet list. It all works as expected.

So no, there are no compatibility issues that I’m aware of between SharePoint 2007 and Excel 2013.